# Flutter desktop 'hover' can not be recognised

Tags: flutter, go, environment-variables, flutter-desktop, gopath

I am trying to run my flutter app on desktop with `hover`.

I ran this command to install hover

`go get -u github.com/go-flutter-desktop/hover`

I have GO installed and the command above finishes the installation without any error, however when I try to use the command 'hover' I get the following error.

`The term 'hover' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1.`

Which I know may mean I do not have it added to my path. How do I add hover to my path. I do not see any file or folder in the installation directory called `hover` .

Comment: You have to add the binary that you downloaded to your path.

Comment: I typed the go get command from my home directory on widows. I do not know where the hover binary was placed. I tried looking for it in the pkg folder and scr folder but could not find it.

Comment: It should be under your Go's `bin` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the binary you downloaded to your PATH.

Assuming your `$GOPATH` is set, you can add `$GOPATH/bin` to your PATH.